# SAML token from ADFS for windows8 app

Tags: c#, windows-8

I am creating a windows 8 client app in c#.This app will use odata service of SAP.
For authentication I need SAML token issued by ADFS.
Is there any method to get SAML token from ADFS using windows credentials?

Comment: why is this not a real question? I think this is quite relevant (though i don't know the answer)....clearly, the person is asking about implementation of ADFS with a Windows 8 app.